Rails 7.1 - Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment when deploying to production via Dokku
I have a Rails 7.1.3.2 app and I am using Dokku to deploy it to the server.
In the process of the deployment, I get this error:
remote: ------
remote: Dockerfile:37
remote: --------------------
remote:   35 |
remote:   36 |     # Precompiling assets for production without requiring secret RAILS_MASTER_KEY
remote:   37 | >>> RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile
remote:   38 |     #RUN if [[ "$RAILS_ENV" == "production" ]]; then \
remote:   39 |     #      mv config/credentials.yml.enc config/credentials.yml.enc.backup; \

I found this/similar issue reported on github, and after adding this recommendation, the error above disappeared, but a similar one popped up:
=====> Start of redata-prod container output (web.1)
       bin/rails aborted!
       ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `bin/rails credentials:edit` (ArgumentError)
               raise ArgumentError, "Missing `secret_key_base` for '#{Rails.env}' environment, set this string with `bin/rails credentials:edit`"
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       /rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
       Tasks: TOP => db:prepare => db:load_config => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)

I am not sure how to deal with the production secret_key_base keys. How do I resolve this error?
Any advice will be appreciated.

If you are deploying a Dockerfile-based application, environment variables in Dokku apps are automatically exposed via build arguments (as of Dokku 0.31.0). This follows Docker's best practices (see docker/docker#13490 for rationale) around environment variables - you can only specify build arguments, not env vars, and they must be explicitly consumed.
You will need to specify a directive in your Dockerfile prior to any usage of the argument to expose the value as an environment variable in addition to exposing the --build-arg docker option.
To expose the build argument, run the following command:
dokku docker-options:add node-js-app build '--build-arg SECRET_KEY_BASE'

Next, your Dockerfile will need to have the following before you use the env var:
# set the argument default
ARG SECRET_KEY_BASE=some-dummy-value

# assign it to an environment variable
# we can wrap the variable in brackets
ENV SECRET_KEY_BASE ${SECRET_KEY_BASE}

See the Dokku documentation for more information.
